# How to create full text index for a multi language column?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, full-text-search

I have a table called TestTable with the below schema.

```
---------------------------------------------------------
ID(Integer) | Text(nvarchar(450)) | LanguageCode(Integer)
---------------------------------------------------------
```

Where ID is a primary key and Text column contains text strings in multiple languages.

I would like to create a full text index on the above table.

```
CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX ON TestTable
 ( 
  Text
     Language <Should get language code from Language column>,
 ) 
  KEY INDEX PK_TestTableID; 
GO
```

How can I achieve this?

Please help.

Answer (score 3):

It's impossible to do it on a single table at the moment. With SQL Server you can only index a column with a single language.

What Microsoft suggest is to use a neutral word breaker (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142507.aspx).

You're query would be as follows:

```
SELECT Description 
FROM Asset 
WHERE FREETEXT(Description, 'Cats', 'de-DE');
```

The problem with this is that you don't get the obvious benefits of breaking in the language of that text.

What you could do is have a view for each culture of the table and index with that cultures specific word breaker:

e.g TestTableGermanView

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled upon this in the SQL docs. I haven't dug much deeper, but it looks interesting.

"For plain text content - When your content is plain text, you can convert it to the xml data type and add language tags that indicate the language corresponding to each specific document or document section. For this to work, however, you need to know the language before full-text indexing."
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142507.aspx